# VSTO for Excel 2007

Tags: .net, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

Can I install VSTO for Excel 2007 in Visual Studio 2022.
I Have Office 2007 in my computer, and I need to build some Add in.

Thanx....

First time using VS 2022 and build an Excel VSTO Add-In is working in Excel 2007, even in VS 2022 it says Add-In for Excel 2013 or newer. There is a warning that an a programme is not install, but when I Open Excel 2007, The Add-In worked.  But now it doesn' work anymore after I make some mistake and had to force shutdown Excel 2007.  After that, the Add-In not checked in COM Add-ins.

What Should I Do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run VSTO add-ins created in Visual Studio 2022 in Office 2007 applications. It depends on such factors like the target .net framework and VSTO runtime installed on the system. Read more about that in the [Run solutions in different versions of Microsoft Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/running-solutions-in-different-versions-of-microsoft-office?view=vs-2022) article.

Comment: Thanx Eugene .......... I will read the article ........  Yes it can run in excel  2007 in my computer, but i still try to make it work on another computer with excel 2007.  I hope i find the answer in that article.